# AS3 copy and paste with colour formatting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, format, copy-paste

This question is pretty straightforward.

I have a bunch of code that I want to put into Microsoft Word. Naturally, I copied and pasted it from Flash CS6, but the colours weren't part of the formatting. It's essential that the colours stay so I can differentiate between keywords, variables, classes, etc.

Is there a way I can do this?

NB: By the way I'm talking pages upon pages of code, I've done a little searching and all solutions I've found so far are to do with code snippets, or other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[online tool](http://www.planetb.ca/syntax-highlight-word)**.

Simply paste your code into the box and from the drop-down list choose `C#` as your code language (is nearest to AS3 for syntax formatting, but you could experiment with the other options).

Now click `Show Highlighted` and a new window will have the code with colour formatting. Just select and copy-paste that into MS Word.

Comment: It's not perfect but it works well enough. I'll mark this as the answer for the time being until I find a proper solution. Thanks.

Comment: The colour formatting shown in IDE is because it's programmed that way, the code you write has always been basic black text. That's why a tool must be used to re-create the effect of coloured keywords & variables etc. If you can install **[NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download)**... that is a better solution. Paste your code, select a language (click **A** then **Actionscript**) then when it's formatted you go to "Plugins"-->"NPPexport" and choose "Copy RTF to clipboard" then switch to MS Word and paste. A bonus is that NP++ also allows keyword / Var colour customizations.